# Laravel subroute name gives error while redirect

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am trying to create admin panel on Laravel. And here is the simple route group:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth'], function() {
Route::get('/',
        [

        'as' => 'dashboard',
        'uses' => 'AdminController@dashboard'

        ]
    );
    });
```

When I try to redirect to dashboard it says Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

but if I redirect to admin directly it works.

Cannot use dashboard to redirect admin index page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing - you don't have here any subroute. You have here only one route - with url `admin`. In your route `dasboard` is name of the route (look at [named routes documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes)) that has url `admin`. So in browser you need to run url `admin` and if you want make redirection you can use:

```
Redirect::route('dasboard');
```

and it will redirect you to url `admin`

or you can use

```
Redirect::to('admin');
```

that will also redirect you to url `admin`.

But better is the first option because if you wanted to change url in future, you would need to change it only in routes file and not in other parts of your application.